# Can we skip naval part in Assassins Creed IV: Black flag

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Is it possible to skip the naval components of AC4: Black Flag?

Comment: I'd actually ask if it's possible to skip the Assassins Creed components of AC4: Black Flag =D

Answer (score 2):

You can't really skip the naval part of Black flags. But you can fast travel. I recon about 60% is naval, as that is the key selling point of the game.

Comment: But fast travel is only available if you have been, at the point you want to travel to, bevor. So I think that the % of naval is even higher, almost all of the main mission have at least some part of naval action in it.

Comment: Forgot to add that yes, then I'd think around 75-80%

Comment: It doesn't have nearly as much naval as you two think. However there are some mixed missions, where you have to sail to catch a ship and then infiltrate it by swimming/climbing etc.